# Discrimination against comments!

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, android-app

While I agree comments are second class citizens, this is just discrimination.

> [image]

I think comments should be treated fairly. The answer draft interface should not overlap the  comment input.

Version: 0.1.31

Comment: Hear Hear. Comments have rights too!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this, the injustice will be settled in the next app update.

[image]

Comment: Version 0.1.34 ?

Comment: Yep, version 0.1.34 which will come out later today.