# SE app devs hate comments ("n more comments" button causes app to close)

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

I know comments are supposed to be second-class citizens, but I think the SE Android app developers have taken things too far this time.

When I tap the "n more comments" button below a *question*, the SE app closes ungracefully (for lack of a better term).  What I mean is that the app disappears, and I am kicked back to the "Home screen" of my phone (where I launched the app from).

I do not get the option to send a bug report, nor does the app attempt to restart.  This one is consistently repeatable for me.

When I tap the "n more comments" button below an *answer*, the app only closes sometimes (I can't seem to find a pattern), and I usually (always?) get the option to send a bug report*.

Stop the tyranny.  Stop the censoring.  Let us have (all of) our comments.

**I may or may not have sent a bunch of these reports with [a description of just "brown."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/209672#209672)  Sorry about that.  Love you, mean it.*

---

Addition info
Phone: DROID RAZR MAXX HD
Android version: 4.1.2
SE App version: 0.1.79

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a Nexus S running 4.1.1 nor a Nexus 5 running 4.4.2. Is it happening consistently on *all* questions or just some?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Its been happening for me for a long time, consistently on questions that I go to from notifications.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Weird!  It's definitely happening on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214404/why-is-the-site-in-read-only-mode) every time.  (thanks for the quick reply, by the way.  You comment-hating-despot, you)

Comment: There's some irony here that I'm discussing this via comments, I couldn't resist.

Comment: [Their hate isn't new](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197047/200868).

Comment: Maybe that phone got a special built in browser with different JavaScript engine? Can you try with Chrome or Firefox? :)

Comment: Ah I seem to not be able to reproduce it due to my insanely fast network connection, from the crash logs it looks like it's a race condition, I'll try to figure out what's going on thanks!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Showoff

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thanks for checking into it!  I had my suspicions that [my shoddy network connection was an issue](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1700029#1700029).  In fact, I get very unpredictable and inconsistent (["crashy"](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=1699962#1699962)) behavior most of the time (because of my network issues).  Should I [make a Meta post about that](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1700057#1700057)?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Yes! That'd be wonderful, we don't do lots of stress-testing for bad conditions at the moment (which we should be doing).

Comment: Cool, @Kasra.  I will write something up to complain about stuff and accuse you of things.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to repro this on my own even after simulating a 4.1.2 phone running on very lossy EDGE and 3G connections, but I'm made what seems to be causing the crash from the report log be thread-safe. I'd be *very* interested in seeing if this still happens for you as of version 0.1.80 coming out sometime around midnight UTC.

Comment: @AsheeshR the app is set to be installable on SD card, but if I remember correctly by default most phones install to internal and then let you later move apps to the SD card.

Comment: @AsheeshR I *just* released 0.1.80 about 20 minutes ago, it'll take 2-3 hours to come out onto the Play store.

Comment: @AsheeshR according to my crash log the one you got upon opening the app is the one I think I fixed in 0.1.80 :)

Comment: Yep I get an automated crash report for everything! The issue is a race-condition so I wouldn't be shocked if it didn't show up one way but showed up another but was still the same root cause.

Comment: @AsheeshR if a full uninstall of the app doesn't fix it, let me know and we can pop in a chat whenever you have time in the next few days to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Got the crash report, I'm still trying to figure out how to get a repro of this on my side so I can actually fix it. I'll hopefully update this answer relatively soon.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi The app finally installed and is working! :) The app still keeps crashing on tapping the "show more comments" option. However, there is a slight delay (~1 second) between tapping and the crash, during which all comments are *visible* (not sure if that helps).

Comment: @AsheeshR yay! I think the crash is a race condition, I can't quite nail why the loading of comments starts it though.

Comment: I've repeated the problem on 0.1.84, although it is less frequent!  I was able to load several question-comment threads before I experienced a crash (on this question, actually).  Then the app crashed twice while I was trying to leave this comment here (eventually just went to desktop to do that).