# Bug in SE App, Crashes when trying to see more comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

The iOS SE app, after the new update, constantly crashes when trying to load more comments. It will crash, in my experience, 100% of the time, and will then go back to my feed which is really annoying when you are either drafting an answer or just trying to read. I've read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214418/332767) post regarding Android, but this issue just started happening on iOS after update from a few days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.5.2 is in the App Store now.  This should fix things.